# Maximum number of edges in a graph with K no. of components.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove:- simple graph which has 'n' no. of vertices with 'k' no. of components has at most $\frac{1}{2}\times(n-k)\times(n-k+1)$ no. of edges.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Please see [this FAQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) on how to ask a good question. In particular, please ask questions and don't give orders ("Prove ...").